# Как генерировать случайный string JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Нужно получить случайный набор букв и цифр (`string`), заданной длинны, например `10`.
Как можно такое реализовать в JS?

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотелось бы увидеть Ваши попытки реализации.
А так - это просто: берём нужный диапазон (-ы) и циклом генерируем случайное значение из него.

```js
let range = (start, end) => [...Array(end - start).keys(), end - start].map(n => start + n);
let A = range(65, 90);   // A-Z
let a = range(97, 122);  // a-z
let dig = range(48, 57); // 0-9
let all = A.concat(a).concat(dig); // Склеиваем в один

function generateString(length = 10){
  let str = '';
  
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    str += String.fromCharCode(all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)]); // Берём случайное число, преобразуем в соответствующий символ и добавляем к строке
  }
  
  return str;
}

console.info(generateString(15));
```

Comment: решений действительно нашёл несколько, но интересно смотреть и анализировать разные варианты кода

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, Ну мы же хотим увидеть Ваше решение!

Comment: Пока остановился на ответ пользователя @Gagablik

Answer (score 3):

Я для себя написал такой код... и не стесняюсь этого)

```js
function createRandomString(sumString){
const symbolArr = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
var randomString = "";
for (let i=0; i<sumString; i++){
 var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*symbolArr.length);
 randomString +=symbolArr[index];
}
return randomString;
}

console.log(createRandomString(10));
```

А так, как Вы хотели посмотреть на другие реализации - вот решение этой задачи в стиле ООП

```js
'use strict';

class hashGenerator {
// startSymbolCode (int)
// finishSymbolCode (int)
// hashLength (int)
// hash - (string || false)
constructor (hashLength) {
 this.startSymbolCode = 48;
 this.finishSymbolCode = 126;
 if (  !isNaN(parseInt(hashLength))  ){
  this.hashLength = parseInt(hashLength);
  this.generateHash();
 }
 else {
  this.hash = false;
 }
}

randomInteger(min, max) {
 var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
 rand = Math.round(rand);
 return rand;
}

generateHash (){
 this.hash = '';
 for(let i=0; i<this.hashLength; i++){
  this.hash += String.fromCharCode(this.randomInteger(this.startSymbolCode,this.finishSymbolCode));
 }
}
}
let hash = new hashGenerator(10);
console.log (hash.hash);
```

Код взят отсюда https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-stCtAm-SU&t=925s

Comment: Ваш код мне больше нравится чем ООП

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно так:

```js
var random = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
console.info(random);
```

Comment: очень мало кода использовали, интересно получилось

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, теперь попробуйте взять больше 11 символов строку :)

Comment: вижу :) тогда придётся всё-же Ваш пример использовать